# Bibliography in Texmaker biblatex still fails

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

Hello everyone,I am new member here and i am facing a problem that has answered in many questions but i think my problem is different. As the title say i canot add bibliography in texmaker. I choosing the wizard in the 'Configure TeXMaker' -> 'Quick Build' dialog, and adding, in the following sequence. Below is my code

PdfLaTeX->Bibtex->PdfLaTeX->PdfLaTeX->Pdf Viewer

What else to do?What is my fault here?

```
 \PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{greenwade93,
      author  = "George Greenwade",
      title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
      year    = "1993",
      journal = "TUGBoat",
      volume  = "14",
      number  = "3",
      pages   = "342--351"
    }
    \end{filecontents*}
    \usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{jobname.bib}
    \begin{document}
      Hello\cite{greenwade93}.
      \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my problem i forgot to run

```
latex file   # or: file.tex
bibtex file  # or: file.aux
latex file   # or: file.tex
latex file   # or: file.tex
```

Also change the line this line of code

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

with this one

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

One more think don't forget to check if you have the latest updates of biblatex. In order to do this Open Miktex and update the package

Comment: Since BibTeX is only considered a 'legacy' backend it would be better to run `biber file` instead of `bibtex file` and have `backend=biber`. You might need to install Biber (via MikTeX's 'Package Manager' - don't try to do that manually) before you can do this and you need to make sure that your versions of `biblatex` and BIber match (this is best done by updating all packages with the 'MikTeX Update' tool - run it at least twice in bot User and Admin mode to be sure).